# Compare overlapping tuple values in a list of Python

Tags: python, tuples, range, compare, overlap

I have got two lists let's say `k` and `m` of tuples that have start and end values i.e., range. I need to check whether any values overlap between `k` and `m`, if yes then I have to increment a variable let's say `tp`. In list `k`, if no overlapping tuple is found in list `m`, then have to increment another variable `fp`. Likewise, in list `m`, if no overlapping tuple is found in `k`, then increment another variable `fn`.

Here are the values in the lists:

```
k = [(76, 166), (273, 384), (472, 659), (820, 860), (970, 999), (1129, 1180)]

m = [(46, 125), (428, 507), (620, 699)]
```

I tried the following but it gives the error `int object is not subscriptable`:

```
k = [(76, 166), (273, 384), (472, 659), (820, 860), (970, 999), (1129, 1180)]

m = [(46, 125), (428, 507), (620, 699)]

tp = fp = fn = 0

for x in k:
    for y in m:
        if((y[0]>x[0]) and (y[0]<x[1])):
            tp = tp + 1
        elif((y[1]>x[0]) and (y[1]<x[1])):
            tp = tp + 1
        else:
            fp = fp + 1
print("tp: ", tp)
print("fp: ", fp)
```

Comment: So fix that error in your data?

Comment: @KellyBundy what's error in data?

Comment: You said they're tuples but one of them is not a tuple.

Comment: Yes, even if we ignore that single value, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the single value it will work, see if this is the effect you want：

```
k = [(76, 166), (273, 384), (472, 659), (820, 860), (970, 999), (1129, 1180)]

m = [(46, 125), (428, 507), (620, 699)]

tp = fp = fn = 0

for x in k:
    for y in m:
        if (x[0] < y[0] < x[1]) or (x[0] < y[1] < x[1]):
            tp += 1
        else:
            fp += 1
print("tp: ", tp)
print("fp: ", fp)
```

Comment: yes it worked fine for `tp` value that comes up `3`, however, for `fp`, it gives the value `15` which is wrong, it should give us `3` because there `3` tuples in `k` which have no overlapping in `m`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the correctness of the code, the value of the result depends on how you set up the logic of the code, try to modify the inequality according to your logic, we don't really understand how you define the overlap problem

Comment: overlap means, if we take first tuple from `k` and `m` there are many overlapping values between `76` and `125`, whereas 1 overlapping value is enough to increment `tp`

Comment: The last 3 tuples in `k` are not overlapping anywhere in `m` so `fp` should be `3`